# "Пользователь печатает сообщение"-Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, чат

Вообще проблем такая,нужно было реализовать что бы при печатание сообщения,собеседнику отпровлялось уведомление о том что вы печатаете сообщение,но у меня получаеться что когда я пчатаю показывает что я печатаю только мне ,а собеседнику нет,как я понимаю отправка не происходит, как отправить?и как лучше на "keydown"-"keyup" или "keypress"?

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

// socket.on - приём сообщения
// io.emit - отправка сообщения
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg, name, dodo) {
    io.emit('chat message', msg, name, dodo);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
    }
    form {
      background: #000;
      padding: 3px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    form input {
      border: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 90%;
      margin-right: .5%;
    }
    form button {
      width: 9%;
      background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    form button {
      width: 20%;
      background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    #messages {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #messages li {
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #eee;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="dodo"></span>
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Who are you?">
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="What do you want to say?">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var socket = io();
      var $messages = $('#messages');
      var $message = $('#message');
      var $user = $('#user');
      var dodo = $('#dodo');
      $('form').submit(function() {
        // Отправка сообщения
        socket.emit('chat message', $message.val(), $user.val(), dodo.val());
        // Очищаем текстовое окно сообщения
        $message.val('');
        return false;
      });
      // Приём сообщения с сервера
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg, name, dodo) {
        $messages.append($('<li>').text(dodo + name + ':' + msg));
        $messages.append($('#dodo').text(dodo));

      });



      $($message).keydown(function() {

        $("#dodo").empty();
        var mes = $("<b>пользователь печатает сообщение...</b>");
        $("#dodo").last().append(mes);

      });

      $($message).keyup(function() {

        $("#dodo").empty();
        var mes = $("<b></b>");
        $("#dodo").last().append(mes);

      });














    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно, также как и для сообщений, выполнять отправку и обработку уведомлений о том что юзер печатает через soket.io.

В серверном коде нужно добавить обработку такого типа уведомлений:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

// socket.on - приём сообщения
// io.emit - отправка сообщения
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg, name, dodo) {
    io.emit('chat message', msg, name, dodo);
  });
  socket.on('typing', function(name) {
    io.emit('typing', name);
  })
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

На клиенте нужно отправлять и обрабатывать уведомления:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
    }
    form {
      background: #000;
      padding: 3px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    form input {
      border: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 90%;
      margin-right: .5%;
    }
    form button {
      width: 9%;
      background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    form button {
      width: 20%;
      background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    #messages {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #messages li {
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #eee;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="dodo"></span>
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Who are you?">
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="What do you want to say?">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var socket = io();
      var $messages = $('#messages');
      var $message = $('#message');
      var $user = $('#user');
      var dodo = $('#dodo');
      $('form').submit(function() {
        // Отправка сообщения
        socket.emit('chat message', $message.val(), $user.val(), dodo.val());
        // Очищаем текстовое окно сообщения
        $message.val('');
        return false;
      });
      // Приём сообщения с сервера
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg, name, dodo) {
        $messages.append($('<li>').text(dodo + name + ':' + msg));
        $messages.append($('#dodo').text(dodo));
      });

      $($message).on('keydown keyup', function() {
        socket.emit('typing', $user.val());
      });

      socket.on('typing', function(name) {
        if (name != $user.val()) {
          $("#dodo").empty();
          var msg = $('<b>' + name + ' печатает сообщение...</b>');
          $("#dodo").last().append(msg);
          msg.fadeOut(3000, function() {$(this).remove()});
        }
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

- как написал @FFFFFF нужно задержку добавить чтобы не нагружать лишний раз сервер.

Comment: Огромное спасибо)Понял в чем ошибка)

Answer (score 2):

1. Чтобы проверить наверняка, откройте эту страницу с другого
   устройства(например с планшета)
2. Я бы делал на keyup, причем правильнее сделать ограничение на скорость печати. Например я печатаю очень быстро и за минуту могу напечатать около 400 символов - если отправлять каждый раз - то получится очень много передачи данных

Лучше отправлять запросы только когда юзер не печатает что-то некоторое время

```
var timeoutId = null;
$('#input').on('keyup' function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
       // Тут код отправки сообщения что пользователь печатает
    }, 3000); // Задержка в милисекундах
});
```

Посмотрел внимательней - конечно другой пользователь не видит что вы печатайте, потому что вы не отправляете в сокет это событие, чтобы все это работало, попробуйте в моем примере выше, на месте комментария добавить отправку события на сервер, например так:

```
socket.emit('writing', 'Пользователь печатает сообщение');
```

И сделайте обработку этого события на сервере

```
socket.on('writing' ...
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

На счет вопроса

> и как лучше на "keydown"-"keyup" или "keypress"?

Используйте keyup + setTimeout, что-нить на подобии

```
var timer;
element.onkeydown = function () { clearTimeout(timer); };
element.onkeyup = function () { 
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
         /* тут ваш код */
    }, 1500);
}
```

Суть в том, что мы ждем какое-то время, после последней отпущенной клавиши ( не все умеют быстро печатать ) и только потом отправляем + keypress не работает с не символьными клавишами ( они его не генерируют, например backspace )
С первой частью вопроса, к сожалению, помочь не смогу(

Comment: Огромное спасибо)